# SQL PostgreSQL - compare sequential rows to determine changes and from/to dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL - Totally stumped on this one - I have a table which stores transactions and need to create a view that shows when a person has changed company. So I need to constantly compare the records (trying to do this with OVER & PARTITION BY) but also need to summarize down to just records only when the company changed but also populate to/from dates based on the data set.

Input Example:

```
Person_ID   Company_Name   Date
1           AAA            1/1/2019 
1           BBB            1/10/2019
1           CCC            1/21/2019
1           AAA            2/1/2019
2           DDD            1/1/2019 
2           DDD            1/15/2019
2           EEE            1/25/2019
```

Desired SQL Output:

```
Person_ID   Company_Name   From_Date     To_Date
1           AAA            1/1/2019      1/9/2019  
1           BBB            1/10/2019     1/20/2019
1           CCC            1/21/2019     1/31/2019
1           AAA            2/1/2019      12/31/9999
2           DDD            1/1/2019      1/24/2019
2           EEE            1/25/2019     12/31/9999
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to get rid of the rows you don't want, using `lag()`.  Then get the to date using `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(date, 1, '9999-12-31'::date) over (partition by person_id order by date) as to_date
from (select t.*,
             lag(company_name) over (partition by person_id order by date) as prev_company_name
      from t
     ) t
where prev_company_name is distinct from company_name;
```

EDIT:

For the question in the comments:

```
select t.*,
       lead(date, 1, '9999-12-31'::date) over (partition by person_id order by date) as to_date
from (select t.*,
             lag(company_name) over (partition by person_id order by date) as prev_company_name,
             min(company_name) over (partition by person_id) as min_company_name,
             max(company_name) over (partition by person_id) as max_company_name
      from t
     ) t
where prev_company_name is distinct from company_name and
      min_company_name <> max_company_name;
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! - Quick follow up, though. Let's say I have another PersonID = 3 with multiple rows, but no change to Company. How can I make sure that PersonID is entirely excluded?

Comment: @nondescriptuser . . . That is pretty easy to add in. However, in general, it is better to ask new question as a new question rather than in a comment.